# Radnom cannot be resolved to a type - Typo error in Java itself

Tags: java, eclipse, random

I have retyped LinkedIn learning material for [Java fortune telling program.](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/up-and-running-with-java-2/implementing-file-operations)

Obviously I do not have typo in random keywords but Java shows runtime error about **Radnom**. Can anybody give me a clue what can cause this error?

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:
>
> Radnom cannot be resolved to a type
>
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ArrayList
>
> Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement at customPrograms.FortuneTeller.main(FortuneTeller.java:15)

Image proof:

[image]

My Code:

```
package customPrograms;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class FortuneTeller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("answers.txt");
        ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
        String answer, response = "y";
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println(rand);
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
            while(input.hasNextLine())
            {
                answer = input.nextLine();
                answers.add(answer);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("The input file \"answers.txt\" was not found." );
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println("The fortune teller is ready for you \n"
                    + "Please think about question in your mind \n and hit enter for your reply");
        }
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The fortune teller says: \n" +  answers.get(rand.nextInt(answers.size())) + 
                "\"\n");
        System.out.println("Do you have another question? (y/n)");
        response = in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Radnom` a typo ?

Comment: Did you copy and paste that code or did you retype it? Retyping often makes problems disappear mysteriously.

Comment: I think the typo is only in the header of the Q.... or the code is not complete

Comment: @Berger I attached image. The issue is really with Radnom, not Java class Random. So yes Java gives me typo error and I do not know why.

Comment: your code copy pasted from here works, just missing `import java.io.File;` and result in an infinite loop but works

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I attached image. Code is complete, I retyped the code first and than copy and paste the one which offers the course. Both codes commit same error.

Comment: [**LOOK AT HERE**](http://ideone.com/7AF8PM)

Comment: @molbdnilo e first and than copy and paste the one which offers the course. Both codes commit same error.

Comment: @JordiCastilla thx for pointing File up. I implemented all imports but code still output "Radnom" error. have no idea why.

Comment: @AndrejBuday Still because of a typo. The compiler doesn't make things up you know.

Comment: andrej, look ideone link I provided... **Your code works**

Comment: Thx @JordiCastilla Locally I still get the same error "Radnom cannot be solved to type". I know that compiler does not make things up. I restarted eclipse, I restarted mac, Radnom still persist. Code in Ideone works, I tried my or code provided by course - both works. Random function also works normally. I will just skip this and move on next page. Problem is really on side of Java, I'm not making this up.

Comment: sorry but no.... problem is in your side... If using eclipse make a last test... `CTRL + H` and search `Radnom` in file search tab you have a typo somewhere....

Comment: @JordiCastilla http://imgur.com/a/plqgK there is 0 findings. I am using for compiling the exact code I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as 15th line is:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

I think I figured out what is going on in your project: **you don't have the `.class` files synced with `.java` sources.**

---

**SOLUTION**

In <kbd>Project</kbd> menu:

select  <kbd>Build project</kbd> option.

After mark <kbd>Build Automatically</kbd> to keep files synced.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you. It was really in sync. I set it back on automatic.